# Should I use 2 GTM Containers while migrating from UA to GA4?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We are in the process of migrating our UA to GA-. Should I make separate GTM containers for both of these properties. If yes, what would be the impact on pagespeed?
How do I make the decision to choose the number of containers

UA to GA4 migration -  Testing

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the complexity of your tracking setup.

Personally, I would not recommend using 2 separate containers to manage the migration. Multiple containers would complicate the GTM maintenance. You'll risk being inconsistent across the containers.

Consider that you will manage the 2 GA properties with different tags so you have full control over the data you will send to GAU or GA4.

Another pros of using the same container is that you can re-use the variables and triggers that you already created.

I hope it helps and good luck with the migration.